# Copying rows via sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, batch-insert

I am trying to insert multiple rows via sql query
scenario is this :
There are multiple attributes against 1 `testID` and I want to copy attributes of one test to another test  by giving their `TestID` here is the query I am trying but its not working at all

```
INSERT INTO dc_tp_attributes
(Attribute_name,acronym,active,description,testId,
subdepartmentid,
DOrder,Attribute_type,D_A_formula,D_A_formula_desc,
Linesno,DefaultValue,interfaced,ClientID,Enteredby,
Enteredon,drived,parentid,heading,print,interfaceid)

select Attribute_name,acronym,active,description,
635,subdepartmentid,DOrder,Attribute_type,D_A_formula,
D_A_formula_desc,Linesno,DefaultValue,interfaced,
ClientID,Enteredby,Enteredon,drived,parentid,
heading,print,interfaceid
FROM dc_tp_attributes
Where testid=877
```

Here I am copying attributes of `testID=877` to `testID=635`, test with ID 877 has 10 attributes and test with testID 635 have just 1.
There is an Autoincrement Primery Key Named AttributeID and the error is

```
"Field 'AttributeID' doesn't have a default value"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the extra parenthesis from the `SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO dc_tp_attributes
(Attribute_name,... interfaceid)

select Attribute_name, ... interfaceid
FROM dc_tp_attributes
Where testid=877
```

Comment: now its saying "Field AttributeID doesn't have default value"...there is an auto increment primary key named Attribute id in this table

Comment: Strange - if the `AUTO_INCREMENT` column is excluded, it should add new Ids with the `insert into ... select` - see this [fiddle example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0b024/1). Are you sure about the auto_increment? e.g. I can repeat this [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/172d3/1)